# ArangoDB lastinsert-Value is NULL

Tags: arangodb

My Query:

I would insert 2 Datasets on 2 Collections with lastInsert Key.

```
LET i = (
INSERT {"lvl": @Lvl, "kapitel_key":@Kkey, "plan_key": @Pkey, "xcontent_key": @Xckey, "user_key": @User_key, "templatefile": @Tf } 
    IN xtemplate 
        LET inserted = NEW
            RETURN MERGE(inserted)
    )
    INSERT {"type": "text", "text": "Write here...", "xtemplate_key": i._key, "user_key": @User_key} IN xinhalt
```

Result:

```
{
  "type": "text",
  "text": "Write here...",
  "xtemplate_key": null,
  "user_key": "2345632"
}
```

Why is `i._key`NULL?

Winke winke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result `i` of your subquery is from type array not document. Every query result in AQL is from type array (see [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Fundamentals/QueryResults.html)).

You have to write `i[0]._key` instead of `i._key` within your second INSERT.

```
LET i = (
INSERT {"lvl": @Lvl, "kapitel_key":@Kkey, "plan_key": @Pkey, "xcontent_key": @Xckey, "user_key": @User_key, "templatefile": @Tf } 
    IN xtemplate 
        LET inserted = NEW
            RETURN MERGE(inserted)
    )
    INSERT {"type": "text", "text": "Write here...", "xtemplate_key": i[0]._key, "user_key": @User_key} IN xinhalt
```